# Closure in Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zE4Y7/

Demo - http://www.ttmt.org.uk/closure/

I have two arrays, one containing phrases, one containing fonts.
I'm using a loop to create 3 div's containing `<p>` tags.

In each `<p>` I'm placing a random phrase from the first array.
Each `<p>` is then styled with the font in the second array.
First `<p>` should be styled with the first font in the array, second `<p>` second font etc.

My problem is all the phrases are styled with the last font in the array.
I think I know why it's happening and I need a closure to stop it.
I'm trying to do the closure like this but it's not working.

Can anyone help me with closures.

```
    <script>

      createFlags = function(){

        var text = ['Hello Sailor','Acid Test','Bear Garden','Botch A Job','Dark Horse','Face','IKEA','Jig'];

        var fonts = ['CALIBRI','CORBEL','SourceSans'];

        for(var i = 0; i<fonts.length; i++){
          var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*text.length); 
          (function(n){
            $('#wrap').append('<div class="font"><p>'+text[ranNum]+'</p></div>').css({'font-family':fonts[n], 'font-size':'3em'});
          })(i);
        }

      }

      createFlags();

    </script>
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with closures, the font is no aplied and thus inherited from the parent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.append` returns not the new element, but the one that you've appened to, so you style the parent div each time. Do this:

```
$('<div class="font"><p>'+text[ranNum]+'</p></div>').appendTo('#wrap')
```

instead of

```
$('#wrap').append('<div class="font"><p>'+text[ranNum]+'</p></div>')
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zE4Y7/1/)